# Text editor for translation of texts without Java?

Tags: gnome, gtk, gtk3, text-editor, translation

Is there an editor, preferable with GTK support, no JAVA ([OmegaT](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/6BIlvPf6QbNNdqYMZa-v1ScgTt94XwCcq7pvtTaHG4zrAQJ2uq5_ty4Fwr2dC4U2qpSbZzS2VQog6aQqGUdEl4QodjYtqTocqZdrNy9BNixrI1l6K6tUICJZ) looks ugly, or am I wrong?), to translate texts like in [Swordfish](http://www.maxprograms.com/images/SwordfishGUI.png) under linux? Or is there a simple editor solution, like a plugin for gedit, which gives me each phrase side by side (e.g. left: original, right: my translation).

I am imagine something awesome like the meld editor, see dummy pictures as example below. Anybody?

[image]

[image]